# General information about object equality in Java

Tags: java

I am currently learning Java game development and am experimenting with positioning entities using vectors/points instead of a primitives. Throughout experimenting I have found something about they way objects work that I don't know how to work around, consider the example..

```
Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
Point p2 = p1;

p1.x++;

if (p1 == p2) System.out.println("these are the same");
```

After changing the coordinate of p1, the println is still processed and after debugging I worked out that by setting p2 = p1, that any changes which occur to p1 will also be made to p2.

Ultimately I wanted to know why this is.. Are the object names just a pointer to a location in memory and both of these Points are pointing to one location?

Also, is there a way around this?

Comment: Because you're referencing the same object.

Comment: Both p1 and p2 variables point to the same object.

Comment: p2 and p1 refer to the same object so when you increment the x coordinate of p1, p2.x will also be incremented

Comment: imagine you have one dog(object) in your house. If two people point (refer) to the same dog, will it *automatically* create a clone of the dog?

Comment: @TheLostMind : cool analogy...but if dogs get *cloned* that would be scary!! :)

Answer (score 1):

> .. Are the object names just a pointer to a location in memory and both of these Points are pointing to one location?

Yes. True. We call that as **`reference`** in Java. Here `p2` is referring to `p1`. Since `p2` is not a `new` Object and it always points to `p1`, what ever the changes you do for `p1` can see through `p2` as well.

An image can explain you more.

[image]

<sub>**Above image copyrights belongs to this [blog](http://javalanguageprogramming.blogspot.in/2013/04/the-new-operator-in-java.html)</sub>

Comment: Or rather, `p2` is referring to the same object as `p1`.

Answer (score 1):

As you say:

```
Are the object names just a pointer to a location in memory 
and both of these Points are pointing to one location?
```

Yes.

In the language of C, this would be something like this:

```
Point* p1 = (Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point));
Point* p2 = p1;
```

The solution of course is to have two different objects on the two pointers:

```
Point* p1 = (Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point));
Point* p2 = (Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point));
```

Or as in Java:

```
Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
Point p2 = new Point(0, 0);
```

Or maybe just initialize the second one like so:

```
Point p2 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
```

It is also worth noting that for `Objects`, in Java, the `==` operator is reference equality, aka "does this point to the same object". If you want to compare two objects based on content, then you should override the `.equals()` method. Most IDEs can automatically generate this based on the properties in the given class.

Answer (score 0):

As you have guessed already, Java object-variables are only references (pointers to memory), thus writing

```
Foo a = new Foo();
Foo b = a;
```

does only create **one** `Foo`-object, which is now referenced by two variables `a` and `b`. Changing the object `b` is referencing will also change the object `a` is referencing, as they are referencing the same object.

Comparing two references with the `==`-operator will check if they reference the **exact same Object**. If you want to compare two objects based on their values, use the `equals()`-method:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
Foo b = new Foo();

if(a.equals(b))
  System.out.println("It seems that Foo() generates Foos with the same values everytime");
```

Cloning an Object is possible by using `.clone()`, but be careful with it, - it only copies the object with all its values by default - no constructor is called, which can cause hard-to-track bugs when calling the constructor is important. I would not advise to use `.clone()` on objects without knowing that it is safe to do it with their class. You can always implement your own `clone()`-method which is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You are right although there is nothing like pointer in Java. Both variables (p1 and p2) are **references** to the same object in memory.

So in your situation you'd probably want something like this:

```
Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
Point p2 = new Point(p1);
```

also what is **very important**: 
when comparing two objects don't use == operator - instead use .equals()

```
if (p1.equals(p2)) System.out.println("these are the same");
```

Answer (score 0):

The base class for Java (Object) has the clone and equals methods so it is part of the base Java system.  However, if you read the documentation for the Object class it has some warnings about what those methods do.  I would use the following and make sure you test it to ensure you get the behaviour you want.

```
Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
Point p2 = p1.clone();


if (p1.equals(p2)) System.out.println("these are the same");
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects and memory.

[image]

I hope it is clear what is show in picture. Finally @BBB and @CCC address cells will be the work for Garbage collector (as both of them has not references with real object now).

We may do a test to show what is going on with real object.

Lets create simple class.

```
class A {
    private int value;

    public A(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void increase() {
        this.value++;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And simple usage to see how the memory links are changed for objects:

```
package test;

public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(1);
        A b = new A(4);
        A c = new A(7);

        System.out.println("a.value= " + a.getValue());
        System.out.println("b.value=" + b.getValue());
        System.out.println("c.value=" + c.getValue());
        System.out.println("\nMemory cells address: ");
        System.out.println("a : " + a);
        System.out.println("b : " + b);
        System.out.println("c : " + c);

        System.out.println("\nAfter b = a;");
        b = a;
        System.out.println("\nb : " + b);

        System.out.println("\nAfter c = b;");
        c = b;
        System.out.println("c : " + c);

        System.out.println("\nAfter a.increase(); All values of all objects will be same, because all of them are linked to one same memory address.");
        a.increase();
        System.out.println("a.value=" + a.getValue());
        System.out.println("b.value=" + b.getValue());
        System.out.println("c.value=" + c.getValue());

        System.out.println("\nAfter c.increase(); All values of all objects will be same, because all of them are linked to one same memory address.");
        a.increase();
        System.out.println("a.value=" + a.getValue());
        System.out.println("b.value=" + b.getValue());
        System.out.println("c.value=" + c.getValue());
    }

}
```

After you run example, pay attention to object references (address)

In my case I received something like below:

```
a.value= 1
b.value=4
c.value=7

Memory cells address: 
a : test.A@6d4b2819
b : test.A@6135b95d
c : test.A@e1cba87

After b = a;

b : test.A@6d4b2819

After c = b;
c : test.A@6d4b2819

After a.increase(); All values of all objects will be same, because all of them are linked to one same memory address.
a.value= 2
b.value=2
c.value=2

After c.increase(); All values of all objects will be same, because all of them are linked to one same memory address.
a.value=3
b.value=3
c.value=3
```